# What does secured object mean?

Tags: java, spring-security

I need to implement my custom `SecurityMetadataSource` ([docs](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/SecurityMetadataSource.html)).

So, I'm reading `Spring Security` and have some misunderstanding about secured object meaning using [**there**](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.0.M1/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/SecurityMetadataSource.html#getAttributes%28java.lang.Object%29). the documentation provides the following:

```
Collection<ConfigAttribute> getAttributes(Object object)
                                          throws IllegalArgumentException

Accesses the ConfigAttributes that apply to a given secure object.
```

and doesn't say anything about what the `secure object` mean. Couldn't you point me out to the definition of this term, if any in the documentation? To me, it sounds too broad and not clear what particular object could be a `secure object`. For instance, if we created an object like `Object o = new Object()` could it be the secure object?

Answer (score 2):

The Spring Security documentation has [a section](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#secure-objects) on this topic:

> So what *is* a "secure object" anyway? Spring Security uses the term to refer to any object that can have security (such as an authorization decision) applied to it. The most common examples are method invocations and web requests.

I've found that this reference explains the concepts and ideas in Spring Security quite well, so take a look.